# Problemas com a codificação utf8 em python

Tags: mysql, python

Erro que recebo ao executar o script:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recebo este erro pelo nome que tem **~** que retorna da tabela do mysql. Se na tabela retirar o **~** no nome não dá erro, se colocar o **~** obtenho este erro.

o meu script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
import MySQLdb
import pycurl
import base64
import json
import datetime

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx.xxx.x.xx", user="xxxxxx", passwd="xxxxxx", db="xxxxxx", charset = 'utf8')

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT DataConsulta, Dias, HoraConsulta, HoraSaida, nome, Consulta, centrodb.LocalConsulta.Descricao, Contato FROM centrodb.RegistoConsultas LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.LocalConsulta ON centrodb.LocalConsulta.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.`Local` LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.UtentesCons ON centrodb.UtentesCons.codigoutente = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.Utente LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.DiasSemana ON centrodb.DiasSemana.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.DiaSemana")

myresult = cursor.fetchall()

for linha in myresult:
 DataConsulta = linha[0]
 Dias = linha[1]
 HoraConsulta = linha[2]
 HoraSaida = linha[3]
 nome = linha[4]
 Consulta = linha[5]
 Descricao = linha[6]
 Contato = linha[7]

 today = datetime.date.today()
 data = today + datetime.timedelta(days=7)

 if DataConsulta == data:
  if __name__ == "__main__":
   url ="https://dashboard.360nrs.com/api/rest/sms"
   usrPass = "xxxxx:xxxxxxxx"
   data = json.dumps({
   "to":[Contato],
   "from":"xxxxxxx",
   "message":"LAR. Consulta de " + Consulta + " em " + DataConsulta + " para " + nome + ". " + Descricao + ". Responda Sim/Não para o acompanhamento. ",
   "encoding":"gsm-pt"       
   })
   b64Val = base64.b64encode(usrPass)
   headers=["Accept:Application/json","Authorization:Basic %s"%b64Val]
   c = pycurl.Curl()
   c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
   c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER,headers)
   c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
   c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
   c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
   c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
   c.perform()
   http_code = c.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
   print(http_code)
```

Comment: Seu banco de dados está com a codificação UTF-8?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss a tabela está com a codificação `utf8 - utf8_unicode_ci`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que você está usando o **python 2**; Essa versão do python faz automaticamente a conversão implícita entre `bytes` (que no python 2 é o `str`) e `unicode`;
Isso pode ser um problema sério para você, pois o módulo json pede `unicode` e você está passando `bytes`.

Uma forma de resolver é trabalhar com unicode em todos os lugares:

```
data = json.dumps({
    u"to": [Contato],
    u"from": u"xxxxxxx",
    u"message": u"LAR. Consulta de {} em {} para {}. {}. Responda Sim/Não para o acompanhamento. ".format(
        Consulta, DataConsulta, nome, Descricao),
    u"encoding": u"gsm-pt"       
})
```

Esse `u` antes das strings diz ao python 2 que as mesmas devem ser objetos `unicode` e não `str`

Dessa forma estará passando unicode para o `json.dumps()` e o mesmo não vai dar problema mais.

Comment: no meu ubuntu tenho a versão 2.7.12 e a versão 3.5.2. Devo chamar a versão mais 3.5.2 no inicio do script?

Comment: @Iniciante se quiser usar o python 3, é só chamar o script usando ele: `python3 /caminho/enviosms.py` mas não é necessário, pode ser usado o python 2; porém a sintaxe é diferente